# unsafeWindow is not defined

Tags: javascript, userscripts

My code is:

```
var $ = unsafeWindow.$, jQuery = $;
$('head').append('<link type="text/css" href="http://twitterchat.p.ht/chatstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitterchat.p.ht/wp-content/plugins/envolve-chat/envolve_api_client.php" charset="utf-8"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitterchat.p.ht/wp-content/plugins/envolve-chat/envolve-chat.php" charset="utf-8"></script>');
```

But I'm getting the error: `ReferenceError: unsafeWindow is not defined`.

I'm new to javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this code being run?  Is this a userscript?

Comment: This on a javascript file and runs on an external page.

Comment: All I need is to display three files on a external website

Comment: Don't see where you declare your unsafeWindow. I think you need to post more code for us to understand the problem

Comment: @KhanhTo: `unsafeWindow` is a built-in feature of certain browser tools, such as Greasemonkey, that let users run their own scripts on web-pages they visit.

Comment: How I can declare the unsafewindow? It's all script.

Comment: @ruakh: I don't know that. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 3):

This is the top SO search result for "unsafeWindow is not defined", so I'm going to answer this for the problem I was having on Tampermonkey in Chromium:

> unsafeWindow is not available if
> `// @grant        none`
> is used.

https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/412

That line is added by default when you create a new userscript, so you need to delete it from the `// ==UserScript==` header block to use unsafeWindow.

Additionally, you can explicitly add `// @grant unsafeWindow` to the header block, though that may not strictly necessary (depending on what you're using to load the userscripts).

More about [`unsafeWindow`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:unsafeWindow):

> The `unsafeWindow` object provides access to the `window` object of the page that Tampermonkey is running on, rather than the window object of the Tampermonkey extension. This can be useful in some cases, such as when a userscript needs to access a JavaScript library or variable that is defined on the page.

Comment: "Additionally, you can explicitly add // @grant unsafeWindow to the header block, though that may not be strict necessary."

The grant is absolutely necessary and the only route by which you are granted access to the page's javascript and resources.. it's kinda the point. entirely really.

Comment: @EdSwangren that depends on which greasemonkey fork and version you're using. The one I was using when I wrote this answer (tampermonkey) did not require it, hence the caveat.